# how to play sequential animations infinitely?

Tags: uiview, uianimation

I have a series of animations that are supposed to trigger one after another with delays. The code that i used works fine but i want all the views that i am animating to animate in a circle infinitely.

this is the code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                      delay:2.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                 animations:^{
                     carouselTextView.frame=CGRectMake(-320, 200, 1600, 150);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                      {
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                               delay:2.0
                                             options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                          animations:^{
                                              carouselTextView.frame=CGRectMake(-640, 200, 1600, 150);

                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                               {
                                                  [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                                                        delay:2.0
                                                                      options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                                                   animations:^{
                                                                       carouselTextView.frame=CGRectMake(-960, 200, 1600, 150);

                                                                   }
                                                                   completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                                       [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                                                                             delay:2.0
                                                                                           options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                                                                        animations:^{
                                                                                            carouselTextView.frame=CGRectMake(-1280, 200, 1600, 150);

                                                                                        }
                                                                                        completion:^(BOOL finished){

                                                                                        }];                                                                       }];
                                              };
                                          }];
                     };
                 }];
```

Comment: @trojanfoe And is that supposed to be funny?

Comment: No it's not funny; I'm sure you can imagine some code structure that avoids this embedded style.

Comment: @trojanfoe Dude come on i am new to programming and stackoverflow. Are you gonna help or what?

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to write all the animation again from the beginning in the completion part, easily all that you need to do is to run the method again, code below:

```
completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [self methodYouNamed];
}
```

Write that code in the completion part, the syntax here is simple, it says **whenever your animation is finished, run the method again, this will not end and will continue forever as you want  **

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll help then.  Firstly you need to discern the *variable parts* of the animation sequence from the *constant parts*.  Provide some sort of data store of the *variable parts* and cycle through them using a method.

So looking at the code, all I can see that varies is this bit:

```
carouselTextView.frame=CGRectMake(...);
```

(note all this code is within your class's implementation file).

So lets store those in a `static` array (it's `static` as I assume the values never change, however if they could change then they will need to be an instance variable of the class):

```
static CGRect _carouselTextViewFrames[] = {
    {-320, 200, 1600, 150},
    {-640, 200, 1600, 150},
    {-960, 200, 1600, 150},
    {-1280, 200, 1600, 150}
};
const NSInteger NUM_CAROUSEL_TEXT_FIELD_FRAMES = sizeof(_carouselTextViewFrames) / sizeof(_carouselTextViewFrames[0]);
```

Next we need to track the current carousel text view frame (an index into `_carouselTextViewFrames[]`). This must be an instance variable:

```
@interface YourClass ()
// private property
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger carouselTextViewFrameIndex;
@end
```

and this must be initialized to `-1` so the first index used is `0` (see `nextCarouselAnimation`, below):

```
- (id)init {    // Or whatever designated initializer is used in your class
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.carouselTextViewFrameIndex = -1;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now the method that will start the next animation:

```
- (void)nextCarouselAnimation {
    self.carouselTextViewFrameIndex = (self.carouselTextViewFrameIndex + 1) % NUM_CAROUSEL_TEXT_FIELD_FRAMES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                          delay:2.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{
                         carouselTextView.frame = _carouselTextViewFrames[self.carouselTextViewFrameIndex];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self nextCarouselAnimation];
                     }];
}
```

And finally you just need to start the animation cycle going by calling `nextCarouselAnimation` from somewhere appropriate (you don't say what your class is derived from, so I don't know where that might be).

NOTE: This code is untested and likely contains numerous mistakes.